# Pull A Section Of A Grepped Line

Tags: regex, bash

I need help pulling Bluetooth addresses from a grepped line.

The addresses are like so:

```
address: 80-82-23-aa-1d-6f, not connected, not favourite, paired, name: "DeviceName", recent access date: 2019-07-22 02:24:44 +0000
address: 4c-6b-e8-01-6d-1e, not connected, not favourite, paired, name: "OtherHeadPhones", recent access date: -
```

I'm able to grep a line for the device I want, where '$1' is a device name and believe I need to pipe this into a regex grep, but can't workout the regex statement.

```
blueutil --paired | grep '$1' | grep <something>
```

I'd require the address line like: '80-82-23-aa-1d-df'. For whichever device name I pass the script ($1)

Any help, and explanation would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Try `sed`? e.g. `sed -n 's/.*\(..-..-..-..-..-..\).*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blueutil --paired | grep '(your regex returning only the line(s) you want)' | grep -P -o '[\da-f]{2}(-[\da-f]{2}){5}'` should help.

- `-P` means that the regex is Perl-compatible.
- `-o` means that only the matches are to be output.
- `[\da-f]` is a hexadecimal digit.
- `{2}` meads that there are two of them in each address part.
- `{5}` means that the address consists of six parts, but the first part, without a hyphen before, has already been matched.

Comment: You could refactor this into a single regex using a lookahead, like `grep -P -o '[\da-f]{2}(-[\da-f]{2}){5}(?=.*your regex returning only the lines you want)'` assuming the regex match should always happen after the address pattern. Keep in mind that `grep -P` is a non-standard extension.

Comment: @tripleee, does this guarantee that the address and device name are in the same line?

Comment: Yes, of course. `grep` only processes one line at a time.

Comment: For some reason I'm having an issue with Grep in Perl-compatible mode. It kicks back an error saying it's an invalid option? Do I need to update anything?

Comment: @Cody depends on your OS.

Comment: Thanks all, took some looking up but I had to install Grep and GNU coreutils separately using homebrew.
brew install grep
Just for future reference, if you're on a Mac older than 2018 apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using GNU `sed`:

`grep "$1" file_name|sed -r 's/address: (.*),\s+not connected.*/\1/'`

Comment: Remember, anything which looks like `grep "x" | sed 's/y/z/'` can be refactored to `sed "/x/"'s/y/z/'`; see also http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep

Answer (score 0):

Probably Awk is a better solution in terms of legibility and maintainability.

```sh
blueutil --paired |
awk -v pattern="$1" '$0 ~ "name: \042" pattern "\042" {
  addr = $2; sub(",", "", addr); print addr }'
```

This contains some guesswork as to which part of the output from `blueutil` you want to match -- in particular, it interpolates the input to search for the string in double quotes after `name:` and a single space.